# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: iphone, load, save, nsuserdefaults

I don't understand what is problem here!
after I compile it, always show me: "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"
I don't know what is the problem! Please let me, thanks.

SAVE

```
 NSUserDefaults *percentChecker = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
 [percentChecker setInteger:0 forKey:percentCheckerSaveKey];
```

---

LOAD

```
NSUserDefaults *percentChecker = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *percentString;

//Alert! 
percentString = [percentChecker integerForKey:percentCheckerSaveKey];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what it's telling you.  `percentString` is a pointer, but `integerForKey:` returns an integer.  Assigning that integer to a pointer is making a "pointer from an integer without a cast".  Why are you saving an integer and trying to load it later as a string?

Comment: thanks.
You were right. I change it to:

 NSInteger  percentString;
 percentString = [percentChecker integerForKey:percentCheckerSaveKey];