# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast C

Tags: c, linux

I am using a structure

```
typedef struct ObjectHandle
{
    long *objHandle;
}ObjectHandle ;
```

A function where the output is the value of this structure

```
AllocateObject(ObjectHandle* objectHandle) 
{
   .... 
   ...
   ...
   objectHandle->objHandle = some long value;
}
```

But compiler is giving warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430909/assignment-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you're assigning the value not to the value (memory), but to a pointer (address)

Try this: 
`*(objectHandle->objHandle) = some long value;`

Comment: compilation warning is gone. but got the segmentation fault :(

Comment: Did you previously allocated the memory for objHandle?

Answer (score 0):

Since It is a long pointer it should have address of long variable.

```
objectHandle->objHandle = &(some long value);
```

Comment: Note: in this case, if variable is local, it will be dead after the code block ends, and getting the value by objHandle address would result in undefined behaviour or segfault.

Comment: Ok in that case you can variable as static.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a long integer to a pointer (objHandle is a pointer to a long). Just like the compiler says.

This is valid c but generally a rather silly thing to do as long integers are long integers, not pointers.

Without seeing what the "some long value" actually refers to, and how the handle is subsequently used, it's a little difficult to indicate whether you should be casting the value, taking the address of it, changing the type of the handle, or something else.